# How to export a matrix in mathematica to some format so that I can read it in python using numpy array

Tags: matrix, export

I have a matrix in mathemtica which contains numericals and one symbol in it. I am trying to export this matix into some format so that I can able to read this matix in python. Below is the matix:

```
Rarz={{{-640227.+195.539 f^2,4211.96 -6.45961*10^-14 f^2,-5469.12-6.30001*10^-14 f^2,-7178.23-1.0631*10^-12 f^2,-336459.+101.522 f^2,-268160.+80.9204 f^2,-216329.+65.2757 f^2,59663.6 -18.0018 f^2,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.683542,0.,0.151787}},{{4211.96 -6.45961*10^-14 f^2,-1.01475*10^7+193.704 f^2,-2958.16-3.10464*10^-13 f^2,-3882.6+1.14274*10^-12 f^2,8.41735*10^6-160.644 f^2,-3.15447*10^6+60.2031 f^2,-2.02112*10^6+38.572 f^2,523032. -9.98159 f^2,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.369718,0.,-0.947078}},{{-5469.12-6.30001*10^-14 f^2,-2958.16-3.10464*10^-13 f^2,-5.13727*10^7+193.708 f^2,5041.45 -2.10639*10^-12 f^2,-3.06998*10^6+11.5746 f^2,-3.30113*10^7+124.465 f^2,2.21776*10^7-83.6176 f^2,-3.85793*10^6+14.5457 f^2,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-0.480068,0.,-1.22348}},{{-7178.23-1.0631*10^-12 f^2,-3882.6+1.14274*10^-12 f^2,5041.45 -2.10639*10^-12 f^2,-1.62352*10^8+193.695 f^2,-3.59425*10^6+4.28872 f^2,-1.71618*10^7+20.4737 f^2,-1.1463*10^8+136.755 f^2,-2.38562*10^7+28.4606 f^2,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-0.630091,0.,1.0085}},{{-336459.+101.522 f^2,8.41735*10^6-160.644 f^2,-3.06998*10^6+11.5746 f^2,-3.59425*10^6+4.28872 f^2,-7.44925*10^6+186.728 f^2,14.5433 -0.00153048 f^2,104.352 -0.0000170639 f^2,181.936 +0.000618984 f^2,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-0.0000174204,0.,0.808413}},{{-268160.+80.9204 f^2,-3.15447*10^6+60.2031 f^2,-3.30113*10^7+124.465 f^2,-1.71618*10^7+20.4737 f^2,14.5433 -0.00153048 f^2,-2.46168*10^7+134.428 f^2,-1.04587-0.000116004 f^2,-226.917-0.000318502 f^2,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.000010075,0.,-0.932321}},{{-216329.+65.2757 f^2,-2.02112*10^6+38.572 f^2,2.21776*10^7-83.6176 f^2,-1.1463*10^8+136.755 f^2,104.352 -0.0000170639 f^2,-1.04587-0.000116004 f^2,-9.49971*10^7+162.914 f^2,121.822 -0.000164648 f^2,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.98034*10^-6,0.,1.03087}},{{59663.6 -18.0018 f^2,523032. -9.98159 f^2,-3.85793*10^6+14.5457 f^2,-2.38562*10^7+28.4606 f^2,181.936 +0.000618984 f^2,-226.917-0.000318502 f^2,121.822 -0.000164648 f^2,-3.5072*10^8+174.856 f^2,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,5.03359*10^-7,0.,2.61313}},{{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-1.62944*10^9+154.953 f^2,-11753.4+0.000111686 f^2,25800.5 -0.0000659562 f^2,-87.1907 f^2,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-9.50724*10^-6}},{{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-11753.4+0.000111686 f^2,-1.23813*10^10+154.953 f^2,-73445.5+0.0000530086 f^2,31.6504 f^2,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.0000927121}},{{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,25800.5 -0.0000659562 f^2,-73445.5+0.0000530086 f^2,-4.75832*10^10+154.953 f^2,-32.2233 f^2,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,3.63798*10^-12,-0.000219237}},{{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-87.1907 f^2,31.6504 f^2,-32.2233 f^2,77.4764 f^2,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-1.,-3.85531*10^-8}},{{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-1.23904*10^9+194.525 f^2,9.69793*10^8-151.126 f^2,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-0.680346,0.}},{{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,9.69793*10^8-151.126 f^2,-4.19983*10^9+227.587 f^2,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.33685*10^-12,0.}},{{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-1.2337*10^10+77.4764 f^2,0.,0.,-2.61799*10^9+65.764 f^2,-1.22465*10^-16,0.,0.}},{{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-4.9348*10^10+77.4764 f^2,0.,1.0472*10^9-26.3056 f^2,2.44929*10^-16,0.,0.}},{{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-1.11033*10^11+77.4764 f^2,-6.73198*10^8+16.9107 f^2,-3.67394*10^-16,0.,0.}},{{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-2.61799*10^9+65.764 f^2,1.0472*10^9-26.3056 f^2,-6.73198*10^8+16.9107 f^2,-3.08425*10^9+77.4764 f^2,-1.,0.,0.}},{{0.683542,0.369718,-0.480068,-0.630091,-0.0000174204,0.000010075,1.98034*10^-6,5.03359*10^-7,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-1.22465*10^-16,2.44929*10^-16,-3.67394*10^-16,-1.,0.,0.,0.}},{{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,3.63798*10^-12,-1.,-0.680346,1.33685*10^-12,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.}},{{0.151787,-0.947078,-1.22348,1.0085,0.808413,-0.932321,1.03087,2.61313,-9.50724*10^-6,0.0000927121,-0.000219237,-3.85531*10^-8,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.}}}
```

I have tried:

1.`Export["strings.fits", Rarz]`

2.`Export["strings.hdf5", tensor, "HDF5"]`

How to do this.

Comment: it might be easier just to generate this 3D matrix in sympy itself than figure how to transport via file. How did you generate this matrix in Mathematica?

Comment: btw, you can't use these format you show to do this, since these are for purely numerical/digital data as far as I see.  _FITS is the most commonly used digital file format in astronomy. The FITS standard was designed specifically for astronomical data_  (Wikipedia)

Comment: I am doing some mixture of numerical/symbolic intergation to arrive at this matrix. I dont know whether sympy can do it

Comment: The title of your question should be on how to read it to sympy Array.  numpy is all about numerical data. It does not know anything about symbols in data,

Answer (score 5):

One easy way is python `pickle`; before that, we should convert your data to a format readable by `sympy`. here are the steps:

Assuming we have only the first row:

```
rawData = {{{-640227. + 195.539 f^2, 
     4211.96 - 6.45961*10^-14 f^2, -5469.12 - 
      6.30001*10^-14 f^2, -7178.23 - 1.0631*10^-12 f^2, -336459. + 
      101.522 f^2, -268160. + 80.9204 f^2, -216329. + 65.2757 f^2, 
     59663.6 - 18.0018 f^2, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
     0.683542, 0., 0.151787}}};
```

1. convert that to python like expression with custom rules:

```
rawDataStr = 
 StringReplace[
  StringTrim@ToString[rawData, FormatType -> InputForm], {"*^" -> "e",
    "  " -> " ", ", " -> ",", " - " -> "-", " + " -> "+", " " -> "*", 
   "^" -> "**", "}" -> "]", "{" -> "["}]

(* Out: "[[[-640227.+195.539*f**2,4211.96-6.459609999999999e-14*f**2,-5469.12-6.30001e-14*f**2,-7178.23-1.0631e-12*f**2,-336459.+101.522*f**2,-268160.+80.9204*f**2,-216329.+65.2757*f**2,59663.6-18.0018*f**2,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.683542,0.,0.151787]]]" *)
```

2. Start a `python` session to use python `pickle` + `sympy` modules :

```
pythonSession = StartExternalSession["Python"];

(* create the symbols exist in your data *)
ExternalEvaluate[pythonSession, "import sympy
import pickle
f=sympy.symbols('f')"]

ExternalEvaluate[pythonSession, "data=" <> str]
```

3. Export the data from python to the local disk:

```
ExternalEvaluate[pythonSession, "with open('C:\\dump.pickle', 'wb') as out:
    out.write(pickle.dumps(data))"]
```

Now you can use `"dump.pickle"` file in any python session you want. Just use the following code:

```python
import sympy
import pickle

f=sympy.symbols('f')

with open(r'C:\dump.pickle', 'rb') as input_file:
    data = pickle.load(input_file)
```

#### Test

To show it's working, I'll manipulate the first element:

```
Block[{f},
 Rarz[[1, 1, 1]] /. {f -> 5}
 ]
(* Out: -635339. *)

ExternalEvaluate[pythonSession, "float(data[0][0][0].subs({'f':5}))"]
(* Out: -635339. *)
```

Don't forget to close the session:

```
DeleteObject[pythonSession]
```

Note for simplicity, the data in python is a simple list, not the `NumPy` array.